# Any suggestion for a good intro to the theory behind economic evaluation of healthcare programmes?

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for an introduction to economic evaluation of healthcare systems.

So, maybe the most obvious answer is *Methods for the Economic Evaluation of Health Care Programmes by Drummond et al.* but I'm waiting with ordering until the release of the latest edition on the 24th of September.

In the mean time I would like to start reading a bit. Are there any suggested (review) articles (journals / web) which can serve as a good introduction? My main focus is on cost-effectiveness analyses.

Comment: See Amy Finkelstein at the MIT.